# how to build a custom JTable in Java, with a row above the column names

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtableheader

I am using  `AbstractTableModel` to create a simple custom table,as usual with a String[] for the column names and Object[][] for the contents in the `JTable's` rows .But, I found it hard to create a table containing an additional row (of one big cell spanning all columns for a general title) before the column names. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: +1 Because you extend `AbstractTableModel`, you have considerable flexibility in the model ,as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438516/display-a-table-of-arraylist/5438607#5438607).

Comment: -1, for extending AbstractTableModel, If you are just using Arrays for the headers and data then why reinvent thewheel when you can use the DefaultTableModel?

Answer (score 1):

by using [BorderLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) you can place `TableHeader` to the bottom of the `Container`

```
add(table, BorderLayout.CENTER);
add(header, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

Comment: user489041 yes, but nothing special for nice look (with Nimbus L&F is nicer)

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you want your general title to look like.

You can easily add a JLabel above the table in a separate panel. Something like:

```
JPanel tablePanel = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
JLabel label = new JLabel( "Table Title" );
label.setHorizontalAlignment( JLabel.CENTER );
tablePanel.add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);
JTable table = new JTable(...);
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
tablePanel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

If you want the title to actually be a part of the column header then it is a little trickier. One way to do this is something like:

```
JTable table = new JTable(...)
{
    @Override
    protected void configureEnclosingScrollPane()
    {
        super.configureEnclosingScrollPane();

        Container parent = getParent();

        if (parent instanceof JViewport)
        {
            parent = parent.getParent();

            if (parent instanceof JScrollPane)
            {
                JScrollPane scrollPane = (JScrollPane)parent;

                JPanel columnHeader = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
                JLabel label = new JLabel( "Table Title" );
                label.setHorizontalAlignment( JLabel.CENTER );
                columnHeader.add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);
                columnHeader.add(getTableHeader(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
                scrollPane.setColumnHeaderView( columnHeader );
            }
        }
    }
};
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
add( scrollPane );
```